# NameError: name 'write' is not defined when writing into file

Tags: python, file, nameerror

Trying to write something into a file but getting

> NameError: name 'write' is not defined

Error when I try to write. I tried both codes and they gave out the same error

What am I doing wrong?

```
with open("/etc/tor/torrc", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("""
    VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
    AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
    ransPort 9040    
    DNSPort 53""")

file = open("/etc/tor/torrc","a")
file = write("""
    VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
    AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
    TransPort 9040
    DNSPort 53""")
```

Comment: `write` is a method of file. You used it correctly the first time. Your last call needs to be `file.write`.

Comment: You didn't precise an extension for your file, is that intended?

Comment: @Fukiyel Welcome to *NIX.

Comment: Did you read the error message you got? Did you look to see the difference between the first block and the second to see why the first works but the second doesn't? (I'm pretty sure the first wouldn't give the same error) Please do your own debugging before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way is correct.
The second way should look like this:

```
file = open("/etc/tor/torrc","a")
file.write("""
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
DNSPort 53""")
```

write is a member method of a file object, so it should be used like this: **file.write(string)**